# Link textbox with listbox in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have two textboxes, one for search to show data from sheet to listbox, and the other to show value.

What I want is any code to show the value in textbox2 after showing the data in the list box. The list box has 7 columns the total value which shows in textbox from the column7 automatically without any command button.

Comment: Can you include some code showing what you've setup so far?

Answer (score 1):

to show in textbox the selected item

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: you don't understand me to clear more i have 7 column in sheet every column contains dat  and when i search the brand in textbox1 show the data in listbox here i want to sum  value of column7 in listbox and show the total in textbox2

Comment: can you show an image with data and desired result ?